# SASS How to set a Variable to equal nothing?

Tags: sass

I am trying to create a variable that is equal to nothing. I have tried the following...

```scss
$false:null;
```

-and-

```scss
$false:" ";
```

What I am trying to use it with is this...

```scss
@mixin myMixin($myVariable:"", $myOtherVariable){
    $false:null;
    @if $myVariable == $false {
       //do something
    }
    @if $myVariable != "" {
      //do something else
    }
}

@include myMixin("", $myOtherVariable);
```

I am using two variables for this example, but I plan to have more than two.

Basically what I want to do is have the option to exclude a variable without having to use empty quotes. And the problem with `$false: "";` Is that it still expects empty quotes. So I am wondering if there is something built into SASS to designate "null / or nothing". I thought it might be null. But that doesn't seem to be the case..

Comment: `Null` is indeed the *nothing* value, but it only exists in 3.2+:  http://chriseppstein.github.com/blog/2012/08/23/sass-3-2-is-released/

Comment: @cimmanon Thanks for the info.. I will double check my version when I get a chance.

Answer (score 47, accepted):

`null` or `false` will work (`null` is new in the latest version of Sass). Both will work for your example. The only advantage of `null` is that it disappears if you use it with a property.

```
@mixin myMixin($myVariable: false, $myOtherVariable: false){
  @if not $myVariable {
     //do something
  } @else {
    //do something else
  }
}

@include myMixin(false, $myOtherVariable);
```

Comment: Thanks for the clarification... Needless to say you have answered my questions about the usage of NULL and it seems to work without issue. I was hoping I could get by without passing a variable in the @include() if I didn't need it. But like I mentioned on maxbeaty's post it doesn't seem like that is an option. Anyways, Null works better as I was running into issues with nil.. So again thanks for your help.

Comment: Wrong again. :) That is an option. With the code above, you have set `false` as the default value for the `$myVariable` argument. As long as you have defaults set for all your arguments, there is no need to pass anything along with the include. Simply `@include myMixin;`. Only arguments without a default will have to be passed with the include line. (Required args also have to come before optional ones in the argument list)

Comment: Okay that makes sense. I knew about optional after required but I didn't know you could set default arguments like that. That makes more sense looking at your mixin now.

Comment: In my case uppercase `NULL` did not work, lowercase `null` did.

Answer (score 0):

Sass is written in ruby which uses `nil` instead of `null`.

```
@mixin myMixin($myVariable, $myOtherVariable){
  $false: nil;
  @if $myVariable == $false{
     color: inherit;
  } @else {
     color: $myVariable;
  }
}

p {
  @include myMixin(nil, $myOtherVariable);
}

.red {
  @include myMixin(red, $myOtherVariable);
}
```

[Example on jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/maxbeatty/n95b4/)

Comment: I am not sure that is the case here. I think this would work no matter what I set $false to.. For example if I used the word "blah" instead of "nil" it would still render the same result. Maybe I am missing something here.

Comment: Make sure you do not quote `nil` as that will make it a string. (`nil` vs `"nil"`)

Comment: `null` is correct Sass, and there is no mention of `nil` in the documentation. See: http://sass-lang.com/docs/yardoc/Sass/Script/Null.html

Comment: [`null` has been made a literal in Sass](https://github.com/nex3/sass/pull/374). [`nil` represents nothing, null, none in ruby](http://raflabs.com/blogs/silence-is-foo/2010/08/12/nil-true-false-ruby/) which Sass is written in.

Answer (score 0):

Set the variable to 'false'

```css
$false: false;
```

Comment: False is not even close to the same thing as Nothing.  Also, the existing answer already covers the False scenario.