# SASS - Set margin to 0 without affecting width

Tags: css, sass

I am completely new to SASS.

This is the SASS code I have

```sass
@mixin set-width-and-margin($label-width: 150px, $value-margin-left: 20px){
    .label-class {
        width: $label-width;
    }
    .input-class {
        margin-left: $label-width + $value-margin-left;
    }
}

.form-1 {
    @include set-width-and-margin();
}

.form-2 {
    @include set-width-and-margin(100px);
}
```

It outputs the following CSS code.

```css
.form-1 .label-class {
    width: 150px;
}
.form-1 .input-class {
    margin-left: 170px;
}

.form-2 .label-class {
    width: 100px;
}
.form-2 .input-class {
    margin-left: 120px;
}
```

I want to add another class `.form-3` and set the `margin-left` value to `0` **without** affecting the `width`.

This is the **desired** CSS output.

```css
.form-3 .label-class {
    width: 150px;
}
.form-3 .input-class {
    margin-left: 0;
}
```

The only solution I know is this.

```sass
.form-3 {
    .label-class {
        width: 150px;
    }
    .input-class {
        margin-left: 0;
    }
}
```

While it does work I want to know if there is a better solution for this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just simply call your mixin with two parameters.  You can overwrite `$value-margin-left` to `-150px` so that the resulting margin-left is `0px`.

```
.form-3 {
    @include set-width-and-margin(150px, -150px);
}
```

If that isn't nice enough, the alternative is to overwrite the margin left after you call your mixin (or, remake your function to accomodate this more cleanly).

```
.form-3 {
    @include set-width-and-margin(150px);
    .input-class {
        margin-left: 0px;
    }
}
```

Comment: The first solution is great, thanks a lot! One more question, is it possible to pass the second parameter without entering the actual value for the first one? Something like `@include set-width-and-margin(null, 40px);`

Comment: No problem!  And yes, it should work: try it!  See this question:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12521197/sass-how-to-set-a-variable-to-equal-nothing