# Does Sass has different operator (!=)?

Tags: css, sass, frontend

In trying to make a mixin in Sass, here is the example

```
@mixin icon($w,$h,$float:'null') {
    width: $w;
    height: $h;
    @if $float != 'null'{
        float: $float;
    }
}
```

But i get an error, I don't know if Sass supports that kind of comparison or i'm doing something wrong...

Comment: possible duplicate of [SASS How to set a Variable to equal nothing?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12521197/sass-how-to-set-a-variable-to-equal-nothing)

Comment: just replace `@if $float != 'null'` with `@if $float != null`

Comment: Actually, my function was working fine but i was having some errors in another part of my file. Also using the -if not- and else works fine, like in the link suggested by @Peter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this:

```
@mixin icon($w,$h,$float: null) {
    width: $w;
    height: $h;
    @if $float != null {
        float: $float;
    }
}
```

or try the documentation http://sass-lang.com/documentation/file.SASS_REFERENCE.html#_9